# DELETE Users in a Razor Page Using asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I would like to delete a user with the following code:

```
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;

    public UserPage(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(string id)
    {
        IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if(user != null)
        {
            var result = await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("UserPage");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

And this is my cshtml file where I get the error : 'Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type UserPage because Userpage does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator''

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>
@foreach (IdentityUser user in *Model*)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.Id</td>
        <td>@user.UserName</td>
        <td>@user.Email</td>
        <td>
            <form asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@user.Id" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

How Could I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `*Model*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'UserPage' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

The foreach statement is used to iterate through an object collection that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface.

So the error is because the type of  `*Model*`  is not correct.You need to change it to an object collection that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comment. I can do this : [BindProperty] public IEnumerable<IdentityUser> users { get; set; } 

But then i get the follow error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You need to give it a default value,`[BindProperty] public IEnumerable<IdentityUser> users { get; set; } =new List<IdentityUser>();`,or you can set it in OnGet.